Accessible public transportation travel information query form
Deutѕchе Βahn has revamped their travel information system, rendering it effectively inaccessible. 
How do I find:

without ECMAScript (except for entirely optional convenience functions),
without cookies,
with advertisement/tracking blockers active,
via the TOR or other anonymization network

information on public transportation timetables
presented in a user‑friendly manner (i. e. no XML response via a REST API or similar).

For buses and streetcars I can usually download PDF timetables from the operator’s or network’s website.
For short-haul trains I know I can check out Kursbuch.Βahn.DE but I want to go long-distance.

None of these options tell me the ticket price, though, in particular demand-driven fares (e. g. the Βahn’s (Super) Saver’s Fare campaign) cannot be assessed.

It works just fine with ublock enabled, and I'm quite sure that, if you checkout as guest, you could do that without cookies either.

What is the problem you are trying to solve here?

@Krist I just want to learn, for example, _when _is the cheapest option to travel Cologne ↔ Leipzig by high‑speed train (ICE) in the month of October. It should be about € 35.8. With that knowledge I can go to the train station and purchase a ticket from the vending machine.

@KaiBurghardt I don't think it is possible with the parameters you gave. The current revision of the website requires JavaScript and some temporary cookies to work properly (though UBlock and TOR should be no issue), especially as you want to have information on demand-driven-fare tickets.
